# Obtain all wordperfect overstrike characters in document for conversion to unicode

Tags: unicode, wordperfect

I am working on liberating a dictionary written in wordperfect 5 to plain text. Ideally I'll end up with a UTF-8 file with each entry on its own line and the fields delimited by tabs, but I digress.

The problem I have is that the dictionary includes a lot of non-ascii characters, which have been composed with (potentially multiple) overstrikes, some of which contain formatting of the overstruck (?) characters. Is there a way to get the full list of overstrikes used in a document, along with their component characters? Unless I'm wrong, this is a necessary pre-requisite to moving the overstrikes into unicode via a script or some other conversion tool.